# How to validate file is selected or not on ajax processed jquery validation

Tags: 7, javascript, ajax

I am trying to do jquery validation on file upload for file is select or not. I want when user click on upload before submit check file is selected or not. if not stop ajax request. Any Idea to validate it?

```
$videoForm['profile_photos']['images']['field_photo'] = array(
    '#parents' => array('video', 'field_photo'),
    '#id' => 'field_photo',
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => 'Photo <em>(optional)</em>',
    '#field_name' => 'field_photo',
    '#process' => array(
    'm_customer_profile_image_remove',
    'm_customer_profile_image_upload',          
    'file_managed_file_process',
        'customer_profile_image_preview',
    ),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://' . $user->uid,
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(array('video', 'field_photo')),
    '#upload_validators' => array(
        'file_validate_size' => array(64*1024*1024),
        'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif jpeg jpg png')
    )
);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If your current code has problems you can post it here and people might be able to point out any problem areas.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for the file upload element? Is this in a form, webform etc.? With the Form API [managed_file](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file) should do what you want.

Comment: Yes i am using a custom form with manage_file. This field is optional.

Comment: The managed_file element has processes attached to it by default. So that you do not override any necessary processes add new ones with `$videoForm['profile_photos']['images']['field_photo']['#process'][] = 'new_process_function';` This might be the issue. **Edit:** you can run the new processes first with array_unshift() instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's Working Example:

```
function yourModuleName_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) 
{       
   if($form_id == "test_node_form")
  {
    $form['field_file']['und'][0]['#process'][] = 'process_test_file';
  }
}


function process_test_file($element, &$form_state, $form)
{
   $element = file_managed_file_process($element, $form_state, $form);  
   $element['upload_button']['#submit'][] = 'validateCustomFile';
   return $element;
 }
function validateCustomFile($form,$form_state)
{   
  if($form_state['values']['field_file']['und'][0]['fid'] <= 0)
  {
    form_set_error('field_file', t('Please Select At Least One File.'));
  }
}
```